# Get child element from a Window Handle in WinUI3

Tags: winrt-xaml, winui-3, c++-winrt

I am trying to find child elements from a parent Window Handle. I have a WinUI3 project which has button in stackpanel. The Sample code is given like this,

In MainWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myButton.Content = "Clicked";

    //IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.).EnsureHandle();

    var window = (Application.Current as App)?.Window as MainWindow;
    var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
}
```

But the problem is I could not find anyway to get element reference for **myButton** from **hWnd**.

Comment: WinUI3 elements are not windows but visuals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/composition-visual-tree so they don't have HWND if that's what you're looking for. Sounds like an XY problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to play a video in MediaPlayerElement using Gstreamer. When I give Window pointer to Gstreamer, it plays the video in whole window but instead of playing the video in whole window I am trying to play the video in MediaPlayerElement.

Comment: Hosting an HWND-element is not possible with out-of-box WinUI3 (search for HwndHost in https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1972). It's possibly technical though but fairly complex (see https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4670). As for MediaPlayerElement there are other ways to use it, but AFAIK not from gstreamer (do you really need gstreamer?)

Comment: Unfortunaley I need to use gstreamer. Is there anyway to tell gstreamer to start streaming inside a MediaPlayerElement? I have tried these two solutions to get handle but failed,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363167/how-can-i-get-the-child-windows-of-a-window-given-its-hwnd 
and this one,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807238/fetch-handle-of-button-using-c?rq=3

Comment: Did you read what I said? There's no handle for elements in WinUI3.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But is there any other way to play inside MediaPlayerElement using gstreamer without getting the element handle?

Comment: Did you read what I said? *"As for MediaPlayerElement there are other ways to use it, but AFAIK not from gstreamer"*

Comment: Sorry I misssed that part. Thanks for the information.